# Python web scraping with user input for captcha challenge

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, captcha

I'm a bit new to using requests and web technologies in general so I'm not even sure if what I want is impossible, or extremely easy. But I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm using requests and bs4 for scraping a website for my own personal use. I don't want the whole website and it is more of an automation task that I've written to make my own life easier. It was working for almost a year until the website used Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge to block my requests.

Now I tried using my browser's cookies and headers to trick the website into thinking that I'm using a web browser to surf it, but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I used cookiejar in requests correctly.

I also used cloudscraper module to bypass this, but it said that the free version doesn't work in Couldflares V2 Captcha challenge. I couldn't even find a paid version and the github page haven't seen any activity in almost 2 years.

But I think it would be better for me to personally solve the Captcha challenge. This way if it changes the challenge and makes it harder my code would still work.
Now I want to know how would one do such a thing?

My exact question is, can I use the requests module in python to get a webpage, send it to my browser for me to see and input some things, then send my response with another requests method? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Requests isn't very convincing in general. The requests it makes look nothing like what a real browser would make. Try Selenium / Puppeteer in other words.